# Logging within a JUL log handler

Tags: java, logging

I've created a new log handler for JUL which extends java.util.logging.Handler.

Is there any standardized way how I can react to errors that occur during the processing of the LogRecord (like LogLog in log4j)?

Just using a JUL-Logger results in another LogRecord that has to be processed by the very same handler.

So, I'm basically looking for a (standard) way how to log messages without creating an endless loop. At the moment, I'm comparing the sourceClassName to prevent such a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, I'm going for this solution:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
  private final static String className = MyHandler.class.getName();
  private final static Logger logLogger = Logger.getLogger(className);
  ...

  @Override
  public void publish(LogRecord record) {
    if (!super.isLoggable(record)) {
      return;
    }

    String loggerName = record.getLoggerName(); //EDIT: Was getSourceClassName before
    if (loggerName != null && loggerName.equals(className)) {
      // This is our own log line; returning immediately to prevent endless loops
      return;
    }

    try {
      // ... do actual handling...
    } catch(Exception e) {
      logLogger.logp(level.SEVERE, className, "publish", "something went wrong", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't shoot down ThreadLocal as getSourceClassName() can resort to stackwalking when not using logp.  If you are really sure you want to id just one source then use getLoggerName instead.

Comment: @jmehrens: You're absolutely right. Seems like ThreadLocals seem to be cheaper...

Comment: There is another solution: instead of calling getSourceClassName(), I could also invoke getLoggerName(), which does not go through the stacktrace. That seems to be fastest solution (if I'm not **again** mistaken ;-) )

Comment: I updated the code to the current solution. getLoggerName() will provide the name of the originating logger. This is the cheapest call so far (no ThreadLocals or Stack inspection needed). Thanks everyone for your input!

Comment: Looks like log4j uses a [thread local guard](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-May/041036.html) to prevent recursion and deadlocks.  That also allows other handlers to log messages.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions that occur inside of the handler should be reported using [Handler.reportError(String, Exception, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html#reportError-java.lang.String-java.lang.Exception-int-).  This reports failures to the installed ErrorManager which can be customized. Using that should take care of most of the endless loops.

However, if act of publishing relies on a lib that also generates log records then you have to resort to detecting the loop. Use a [java.lang.ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and some sort of enum to track the state changes.

```
public class HandlerReentrance extends Handler {

    private static final Level PUBLISH = Level.ALL;
    private static final Level REPORT = Level.OFF;

    private static final ThreadLocal<Level> LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        if (LOCAL.get() == null) {
            LOCAL.set(PUBLISH);
            try {
                doPublish(record);
            } finally {
                LOCAL.remove();
            }
        } else {
            final Level last = LOCAL.get();
            if (PUBLISH.equals(last)) {
                LOCAL.set(REPORT);
                try {
                    reportLoop(record);
                } finally {
                    LOCAL.set(last);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void doPublish(LogRecord record) {
        if (isLoggable(record)) {
           //Insert code.
        }
    }

    private void reportLoop(LogRecord record) {
        //Insert code.
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the extreme cases?

Comment: @geoffrey-wiseman If you build a handler for lib that has a logging/debugging infrastructure.  In that case the handler is attached to the logger and the act of publishing uses the lib which in turn uses the logging API.  My experience is with JavaMail and MailHandler but this same type of thing would happen with the JDBC API and a DbHandler

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Handler.reportError(String, Exception, int). I took a look at the implementation and was not too happy about it. It simply prints the error to System.err. The ThreadLocal variant seems to be a good solution, except for the cost (in terms of performance) of handling ThreadLocals in general. I think I'll go for the SourceClassName. This way, the log message can be forwarded to all other handlers.

Comment: @Roman The behavior is determined by the assigned ErrorManager.  Install a custom error manager to change the behavior.